# First time I've built a class, but IDE is throwing up a syntax error; not shown when functions/variables are extracted from class?

Tags: php, oop, class

Finally, I'm getting into OOP and attempting to put together my first class. However, my IDE (NetBeans) throws up an error on the last function's (`sanitize()`) closing parentheses. This doesn't happen when all the class contents are extracted from the class.

**Here's my code:**

```
class db_class {

    $error_log = false; 

    function connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) {
        $connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
        return $connect;
    }

    function select_db($db_database) {
        $select_db = mysql_select_db($db_database);
        return $select_db;
    }


    function array_prepare($data) {
        $size = sizeof($array);

        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $keys[] = $k;
        }

        $size_md = sizeof($array[$keys[0]]);
        for($i = 0; $i < $size_md; $i++) {
            $value .= '(';
            for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++) {
                    $value .= "'".$array[$keys[$j]][$i]."',";
            }
            $value = rtrim($value, ',');
            $value .= '), ';
        }
        $value = rtrim($value, ',');

        return $value;
    }

    function sanitize($data) {
        if(is_array($data)) 
        foreach($data as $k => $v) 
            $data[$k] = sanitize($v); //recursive
        elseif(is_string($data))
            $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        return $data;
    } // <- where the error is thrown up  

}
```

I really don't see what I've done wrong, and the suggestions offered by NetBeans are many (it offers like 10 explanations for the syntax error). Can anyone pick up what could be causing this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a [visibility declaration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) on your property.

In other answers they have you use `var`, however I would advise you to use PHP5 visibility declarations; `public`, `protected` or `private`.  The visibility of the variable should be based on the need for that piece of data.  As a general rule though, you should limit the amount of properties that are declared `public`.  Ultimately, you have no control over the data that can be assigned to a `public` property.

Furthermore, you should put a visibility declaration on your functions as well.  Not having any visibility declaration will mark them as `public`, this is probably not what you'll want for all functions in a class.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Having just spent the last 20 minutes reading through the PHP.net Doc's on Classes; I've learnt a lot - but I don't understand why in this instance I wouldn't want my functions to be declared `public`? I was expecting to call them like `$class->function()` all the way along; rather than have them for exclusive usage within the class. Or were you talking in general; as I do understand why one would want to declare the visibility on a function.

Comment: As far as the visibility on functions I was speaking more generally.